# Printing receipt from the listview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Hi I have a form for pharmacy purchase but the print/confirm button have errors. The error occurs when it is printing. I just found this codes on a tutorial online and I want to use it.

This is the error I got when pdf is printing.[image: Error]

The error is from the `float cash = float.Parse(txBCash.Text.Substring(1, 3));`

This is the codes

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();

        printDialog.Document = printDocument; //add the document to the dialog box...        

        printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt); //add an event handler that will do the printing

        //on a till you will not want to ask the user where to print but this is fine for the test envoironment.

        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print();

        }
    }
    public void CreateReceipt(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        int total = 0;
        float cash = float.Parse(txBCash.Text.Substring(1, 3));
        float change = 0.00f;

        //this prints the reciept

        Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up

        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 10;
        int offset = 40;

        graphic.DrawString(" Kwem Drugstore", new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
        string top = "Item Name".PadRight(30) + "Price";
        graphic.DrawString(top, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
        graphic.DrawString("----------------------------------", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5; //make the spacing consistent

        float totalprice = 0.00f;

        foreach (string item in listViewOrders.Items)
        {
            //create the string to print on the reciept
            string productDescription = item;
            string productTotal = item.Substring(item.Length - 6, 6);
            float productPrice = float.Parse(item.Substring(item.Length - 5, 5));

            //MessageBox.Show(item.Substring(item.Length - 5, 5) + "PROD TOTAL: " + productTotal);

        }

        change = (cash - totalprice);

        //when we have drawn all of the items add the total

        offset = offset + 20; //make some room so that the total stands out.

        graphic.DrawString("Total to pay ".PadRight(30) + String.Format("{0:c}", totalprice), new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + 30; //make some room so that the total stands out.
        graphic.DrawString("CASH ".PadRight(30) + String.Format("{0:c}", cash), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("CHANGE ".PadRight(30) + String.Format("{0:c}", change), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 30; //make some room so that the total stands out.
        graphic.DrawString("     Thank-you for your purchase,", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("       please come back soon!", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);

    }
}
```

I don't know if this is correct or if i'm doing it correctly. But please help me resolve this because for our project in our school.

Any type of response is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the text present in your txBCash textbox?

Comment: @Steve the txBCash is the amount being paid by the customer for the orders.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly has been typed there? Do you have at least 4 characters? If not then you get the IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes in C# starts at zero, not at 1. And the second parameter of the Substring method is not the end position but the length of characters to retrieve. So your code asks for 3 characters from the txBCash textbox starting from the second character typed. If you want to get the first three characters then you should write

```
float cash = float.Parse(txBCash.Text.Substring(0, 3));
```

But a better approach is through float.TryParse that doesn't trigger an exception when the input is not a valid float. Of course you cannot be sure that your user types just 3 characters in that textbox, so I would remove also the starting and the length limits

```
float cash = 0.0;
if(!float.TryParse(txBCash.Text, out cash))
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid value for cash");
```

Comment: Thank you very much steve. This one helps me.